# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:16

Tags: nginx, configuration

I am new to linux + nginx. I've installed nginx and tried to do some modifications in ~/sites-available/default file but forgot to make a backup of this file. So, now I get following error:

nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default test failed

Please, tell me where the error is. Here is default file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
#

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: The error is in a different file in sites-enabled.

Comment: Please run `nginx -t` to check your configuration where the error occurs, please provide us also the content of that config file.

Comment: `forza@debian-512mb-fra1-01:~$ sudo nginx -tc /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Result:

`nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default test failed`

The contents of *sites-enabled* are the same as above

Comment: I already provided above a file contents:


Command:

`forza@debian-512mb-fra1-01:~$ sudo nginx -tc /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Result:


`nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default test failed`

Comment: May I see the contents of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`